# Machine B use A as gateway

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have two Linux machines, A and B both connect to internet.

I want machine B to use A as Gateway.
Anyone connected to B there request send to A and then go two the internet.

User1,User2 --> B(IP2) --> A(IP1) --> internet.
A and B not in same network (not connected with LAN), their request should transfer over something secure but prefer do that with routing or somthing like this not use openvpn or wiregurd if it is possible.

It is like everybody connect (over internet) to B, but their internet became from A.

If anybody, ssh to system B and ping google. Their request send to A then go to the internet.

Comment: If they don't both have public IP addresses this can't be done without VPN or wireguard.

Comment: This is a how-to question. It's better if you use Google to research using one of the many methods to do this and ask a question if you are having trouble.

Comment: Both of them has public ip. I do research but a little confused about that . Some how should set IP routing rule but I am not find something useful about that. But itr6 again

Comment: If both systems have public IP addresses, why do you want B to route though A? If A and B are not in the same LAN, how are they connecting to each other? And, if you ssh to B, should that connection be forced to be routed though A?

Answer (score 0):

Your new architecture will be better than your actual.
Since machine A will be a central point, you will have only one firewall to manage. And it will be the ideal place to install network management tools like IDS.

On machine A (with 2 network adapters):

- configure 2 network segments (let's say netA and netB, netA being the one connected to router). Address of network adapter A must be in the same segment than router.
- Assuming you're using IPV4, activate ip_forward parameter.
- set the gateway address to your Internet router address.

On machine B (1 network adapter):

- set the IP address to the address of network adapter B on machine A.

Install an ethernet cable between A (adapter B) and B.
Install an ethernet cable between A (adapter A) and the router.

That's all
PS: I don't understand what you mean by "A and B not in same network (not connected with LAN)"

Comment: A an B is two is in different country. For example one in Brazil other in France. No lan connection between them they just can see each other IP from internet.

Comment: OK! That's different. It works the same way but you need to fully open the router and let everything go through. I DO NOT RECOMMAND THAT WAY. One alternative is to implement a VPN between B and A (as proposed by @tink). Another alternative would be to create a SSH tunnel between B and A. You may also want to block any Internet access (except A) through the router on B side.